# TypeScript - Append type to end of Tuple type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is it possible to write a helper that will append an additional type to a given tuple type?

```
type A = Append<['a', 'b'], 'c'> // resulting in ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

I would also be interested in joining 2 tuple types:

```
type B = Join<['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']> // resulting in ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In TS it is quite simple to write functions which will shift and unshift elements from the tuple. Consider:

```
type Shift<T extends Array<any>> 
= ((...a: T) => any) extends ((a: any, ...result: infer Result) => any) 
? Result 
  : never;

type Unshift<A, T extends Array<any>> 
= ((a: A, ...b: T) => any) extends ((...result: infer Result) => any) 
? Result 
  : never;

type A = Shift<['a', 'b', 'c']> // A is ['b','c']
type B = Unshift<'a', A> // B is again ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

But you have ask about other way round, this is more tricky but by using above `Shift` and `Unshift` its doable. Consider:

```
type Append<
  T extends any[]
  , A
  , ReducedT extends any[] = T
  , Result extends any[] = [A]
  , Rest extends any[] = Shift<ReducedT>
  , Last extends T[keyof T] = T[Rest['length']]
  > = {
  [K in keyof ReducedT]: Rest['length'] extends 0 ? Unshift<Last, Result> : Append<T, A, Rest, Unshift<Last, Result>> 
}[0]

type R = Append<['a', 'b', 'c'], 'd'>
// ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

type Merge<
  A extends any[]
  , B extends any[]
  , ReducedA extends any[] = A
  , Result extends any[] = B
  , Rest extends any[] = Shift<ReducedA>
  , Last extends A[keyof A] = A[Rest['length']]
  > = {
  [K in keyof ReducedA]: Rest['length'] extends 0 ? Unshift<Last, Result> : Merge<A, B, Rest, Unshift<Last, Result>> 
}[0]

type AB = Merge<['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d','e','f']>
// ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e','f']
```

Full code is available in [the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=41&ssc=33&pln=15&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAygFgSwGbADwBUoQB7AgOwBMBnKAQQCcKBDEVa-EAPiagFgAoAXigApeAdEOoAuKOgCUULqwYgpOPEVL9RUOQBooQgRQjEArgBtgYhPiQQKUAEr7jwKTPWMpnAPy37J9hyhQxfAgANysAbk5OUEgoAFV8YkQUVDItTEUCEnIqWnpGFl8eVTFU7SEAIzFJaVlXLFxMlUEhPUMTMwsrLzbHGpd5X087Ht9-QJDwyI5o6DJpWCS0AG0AcmoVrRXyjagVgGMVgF1WAHoT8igEUlXtjX2jqPBoACF5%20MTkNDWdslPz16u6gA5tRzFBVutNrddgdDlNHjEyGBIERUJx-OkGsp%20ks4X4oFoyOiCV5CAY9hBCJilFk5Lj5uhiVphg56jTSHTDvMlmQ8f5mfpgGzGjiuTx4J9UHYyRSqUwmVAADLUYhCjLY9BLADWEBAAHskOIxeIlsNgKsjAQgcA4Ec%20VBWDwAN7EpYAaUu%20CgOv1hul5Mp6EOYjNFqtNqOwuxAAYoJ53otUMrVQKeqwSsjMhhCangFoE5Lk3nug4CpwAL5LaN4hHQGzzJEowioCE7LZt2GbQgreUcM7g75Qjtt7s16ZPKAAWSsQIgaPxc3VtMYuIVryXHJX9oFMspi6xy5A9J4RPxqdZG9F82eCrNUcPx4Wkv9st%20CqL99IZG1uoN5GN36hislr4NatqHPajpQC6%20Lup63q-n6lIBoQvIhoKYagRGXKXrG8YJImRbniY6ZTjOc6lM8ub5gRhYqsWLIkawFZVmOMzkK8PDThQs4toOuzQvchxaKs3Z3BAGwrEgRy9v2rZDpsBxdm2El3NJhxAA).

Both types are based on recursion types, for example taking the first type `Append`:

- `ReducedT` is an array which we will use to take out elements from the original Array
- `Result` - this is our final array, we put things to it (pay attention we start from `[A]` so from element we want to have last
- `Rest` - it represents next iteration of `ReducedT` so we shift one element out
- `Last` - last element from original array
- `Rest['length'] extends 0 ? Unshift<Last, Result> : Append<T, A, Rest, Unshift<Last, Result>>` - every iteration checks if our reduced array is not empty, if is we do last unshift and end the recursion, if its not empty we Append again with smaller `ReducedT` and bigger `Result` as we shift from one and unshift to the second.
- `[K in keyof ReducedT]` is here only to trick TS type system, as without it TS would complain about infinite call

Comment: This is great thanks. Out of curiosity what is `[K in keyof ReducedT]` doing to trick the type system? I've tried recursive types a couple of times and not been able to understand why sometimes you get an infinite call error and sometimes you don't.

Comment: Here its really a way to skip the infinite call error. Take a look that `Rest['length'] extends 0 ? Unshift<Last, Result> : Merge<A, B, Rest, Unshift<Last, Result>>` does not use even `K`, its here only to skip the TS limitation.